# Finding a preimage

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

How do I do this I've got stuck.

$f^{−1}([0, 2])$ for $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) =$

$0$ for $x < 1$

$x$ for $x ≥ 1$.

I've managed to draw a graph to represent it but further than that the proof has baffled me.

Comment: Hi Aristotle. How is the graph you draw and why it didn't help you to solve the problem?

Comment: Is it between 1,2?

Comment: I asked first...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Split the interval as: $(0,2)=)0,1]\cup [1,2)$ and find:

$$
f^{-1}[0,1) \quad \mbox{and} \quad f^{-1}[1,2]
$$